# Gerrit - Application Error - Intraline difference not available due to server error

Tags: gerrit

For one of our gerrit projects, while navigating the file differences we get this error:

Application Error

Intraline difference not available due to server error

[Continue]

It doesn't happen for all projects, currently we've detected the error on only one project.

I looked on Google and on the gerrit documentation. Found a reference on their source code, but don't know what causes it and how it can be resolved.

The web page with the error contains a "Continue" button. Once clicked it will take you to the file you selected, but the error is annoying.

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

That is caused while cache the intraline difference of one file, when compared between two commits. The default timeout value is 5 seconds. If the file is huge, and computation takes longer than the timeout, the worker thread is terminated, an error message is shown, and no intraline difference is displayed for the file pair.

A solution could fix this.

1. Add config in gerrit.conf.

   [cache "diff_intraline"]

   timeout = 15000 ms    # Or other time length as you want.
2. restart Gerrit service
3. run SSH command "gerrit flush-caches", using a user with ViewCaches global capability.

   *ssh -p port userxxx@host gerrit flush-caches*

Then it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Cause of the error:

It is a result of Gerrit taking too long to diff the file, and marking the diff in one of its caches as non-available.

The relevant error log is here:
[2012-06-08 11:14:08,547] WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.patch.IntraLineLoader : 5000 ms timeout reached for IntraLineDiff in project xxxxxxx on commit 354dd67ad54578cf801d8cda64a4ae8484ebb0b7 for path xxxxxxx.java comparing bf9fbc21520af7bfd0841c8b9f955ca6e215b059..f6b9c7992c12cfdca253acd033966f98f70f3543.  Killing IntraLineDiff-6